# Mosquitto broker takes a long time to start and has a high cpu usage

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I am running a mosquitto broker on a Debian stretch ARM devices(similar to Raspberry Pi).

But the mqtt broker takes about 2mins to start(ready to be connected), and it occupies 100% CPU when it starts.

[This is the link of a screenshot of 100% CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG6Rh.png)

I also notice that if I start the mqtt broker without `-c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`, the broker starts immediately with low cpu usage.

This is my mqtt config file:

`~$ cat /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf 
bind_address 0.0.0.0
port 1883
protocol mqtt`

And my mqtt broker version is 1.5.5:

`sudo mosquitto --help
mosquitto version 1.5.5
mosquitto is an MQTT v3.1.1 broker.`

Why my broker takes such a long time to start?
Any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: I have tried the version 1.4.10 (install from apt) before, and that doesn't work. I have checked my system that port 1883 isn't occupied.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer finally. The reason is that /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db is too large(12MB). It takes a long time to load that database. So I just removed it and set `persistence false` in the config file.